# How can i get my C# winform browser open up a webpage without using a web-browser control ?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made it open HTML sourcecodes using the HTMLwebrequest and HTMLwebresponse commands. But someone please help me on how can i view a webpage content on the click of a button on the winform. (Without the help of a webcontrol).

Comment: And where do you want see your html?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to render HTML to a control in your form without using a [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Why would you specifically rule out the one control designed to do exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: yes rendering html without a webcontrol and show it in richtextbox. Its a part of my assignment.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is by passing a valid URL to

```
Process.Start(yourURL);
```

[Process.Start Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your PC should then open your default browser with that URL